# One action happens before another action verification

Tags: clauses

Is there any meaning difference among the below sentences?

> **After finishing** her work, she went home.
>
> **After she finished** her work, she went home.
>
> **Having finished** her work, she went home.
>
> **When she finished** her work, she went home.

Comment: No, there isn't. Some constructions might suit some contexts slightly better than others but they mean the same thing; She finished her work. Then she went home.

Comment: Thank you @RonaldSole . Which ones are slightly better than others.

Comment: There is no difference in quality. All are concise and grammatical.

Comment: There *is* a difference in meaning, but it's extremely subtle and not enough to make any practical difference. (Plus it would be open to interpretation anyway.)

Comment: Which pair do you think has a subtle difference ? @JasonBassford

Comment: They all do. Anytime you use a different word, there is always *something* different, it's just a matter of degree. And the more different words you use, or the different ways in which you order them, the greater the difference.